# Relation between invariant subspaces and eigenspaces of a vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to establish to figure out a connection between *invariant*
subspaces and *eigenspaces* of a vector space $V$.

Let $A \in End(V)$, $V$ vector space. Consider $W \le V$ a subspace with $\dim W =1$, that is $A$-invariant ($AW \subseteq W$). I want to show that $W \subseteq V_\lambda$.

For some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ we have

$$V_\lambda = \{v \in V\ \, | Av = \lambda v\, \}$$

is the *eigenspace* associated to the some eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Since $\dim W = 1$ we have that $W=span\{w\}$.

Now, I would say that $Aw = aw$ because $W$ is $A$-invariant.

My question is, should I assume that $a = \lambda$ and therefore $W \subseteq V_\lambda$?

In general, is there a *bijection* between invariant subspaces and *eigenspaces*?

Comment: You can't quite "assume $a=\lambda$". You say "for some $\lambda$ [etc]", when in fact every $\lambda $ has that property. Instead, _start_ with $a$, then **set** $\lambda=a$.

Comment: But can we **set** the value of $\lambda$ based on $a$?

Comment: You say you want to show that $W\subset V_\lambda$. That's not a "sentence" in the sense of formal logic because you haven't specified the quantifier on $\lambda$. What you actually want to show is this: "_there exists_ $\lambda$ such that $W\subset V_\lambda$." And yes, if you're proving _that_ then you can legally set $\lambda$ to anything you like.

Comment: Got it, many thanks. I definitely have gaps in some basic topics..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In finite dimension the question is well known.

Let $V$ a $K-$vector space, with $dim(V)=n,$ and let $W\subset V$ is $A-$invariant, with $dim(W)=m.$ If $m=1$ and $W=Span(\{v\})$ then $Av\in W,$ and exists $\lambda\in K$ such that $Av=\lambda v,$ hence $W$ is contained in the eigenspace with related eigenvector $\lambda.$ In higher dimension, since $W$ is $A-$invariant the restriction of $A$ to this subspace is a well-defined endormophism, and its eigenvalues are also eigenvalues of the given $A.$

In summary each eigenspace is invariant (for instance the kernel, which is the $0-$eigenspace), but the converse is not true in general: $Im(A)=\{v\in V: \exists w\in V, Aw=v\}$ is clearly $A-$invariant, but not always an eigenspace.

Comment: Got it! So the image is an example of invariant space that is not always an eigenspace.